# scrapy spider name definition and/or restrictions

Tags: python, scrapy

Using scrapy example that has:
spider in *.py coded as

```
class ArticleSpider(spider):
    name="article"
```

When I run `scrapy check -l` or `scrapy crawl article` I get an error:

```
    class ArticleSpider(spider):
NameError: name 'spider' is not defined
```

I changed to `Spider`, `scrapy.spider`, etc. and receive the same error. I looked at scrapy.org, etc., for definitions and/or restrictions on (spider) but can not find any. So what causes this error?

Comment: This isn't a Scrapy error.  This is not understanding a fundamental of Python.  A `NameError` is raised when a variable isn't found.  I'd highly recommend reading up on, and getting a firm understand of, the basics of Python before you get started with Scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not about the Spider name but from the class you inherit from. That being said:

You must inherit from **Spider**:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
```

Then:

```
class ArticleSpider(Spider):
    name="article"
```

Please take in account that **class names are case sensitive**.

If you need more information, please refer to:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider

Comment: Hi Andres:  I am using Python 2.7.6. After I spelled the from statement correctly it ran OK.  Thanks. for the reference,  Bob

Comment: @Yankee26 that's great! If you think my answer is correct please set it as the answer to your question.